# Vagrant don't work since Docker toolbox's install on Windows

Tags: windows, vagrant, docker-toolbox

I installed docker-toolbox on Windows to give it a try. It seems to be working find.

But my vagrant stopped working. Now when I try to `vagrant up` (completely different project), I see:

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions
listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3
```

Not sure what I should do to fix this. If I remove/install Virtualbox, will it still work with docker-toolbox?

Running on

- Windows 7
- Vagrant 1.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Toolbox has installed VirtualBox 5.0

upgrade vagrant to 1.7.3 and it will support (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5572) ideally upgrade to vagrant 1.7.4